# Drupal wysiwyg question

Tags: drupal-6

Hi all i have a question. I have the wysiwyg module installed and i think configured the correct way but there is one problem. After writing my content in the editor the content doesnt show up in my blog posts.

Any one having the same problem ?.

Comment: Guys i have solved my own problem here. It turns out that i had a faulty filter turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys i have solved my own problem here. It turns out that i had a faulty filter turned on.

Comment: +1 for follow up with own findings - don't forget to accept your own answer eventually